# Trying to train the ImageNet model with Region CNN (R-CNN)

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

After several month working with [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe), I've been able to train my own models successfully. For example further than my own models, I've been able to train ImageNet with 1000 classes.

In my project now, I'm trying to extract the region of my interest class. After that I've compiled and run the demo of [**Fast R-CNN**](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn) and it works ok, but the sample models contains only 20 classes and I'd like to have more classes, for example all of them.

I've already downloaded the [**bounding boxes**](http://image-net.org/download-bboxes) of ImageNet, with the real images.

Now, I've gone blank, I can't figure out the next steps and there's not a documentation of how to do it. The only thing I've found is how to train the INRIA person model, and they provide dataset + annotations + python script.

My questions are:

- Is there maybe any tutorial or guide that I've missed?
- Is there already a model trained with 1000 classes able to classify images and extract the bounding boxes?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dr Ross Girshik](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/) has done a lot of work on object detection. You can learn a lot from his detailed git on [fast RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn): you should be able to find a caffe branch there, with a demo. I did not use it myself, but it seems very comprehensible.

Another direction you might find interesting is [LSDA](http://lsda.berkeleyvision.org/): using weak supervision to train object detection for many classes.

BTW, have you looked into [faster-rcnn](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497)?

Comment: Hello @Shai, thanks for answering. To be honest I didn't know about LSDA or faster-rcnn, I'm going to take a quick look to both of them. LSDA seems to be clear. The point of the git of Ross Girshik is that I'm not able to understand how to train since there's not a "download set" like regular Caffe, it allows to download only the pre-trained models or train models with 20 classes.. I'll take a deeper look if things are "clear" as you mention, because maybe I passed some details that I needed... will see the rest of frameworks and will update the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @RafaelRuiz AFAIK fast-rcnn git has a training script (in python) based on VOC annotations, I believe (= I did not try it myself) it can be changed to work with other annotated sets as well.

Comment: I'll give a try, thank you very much. I've seen that script now, but I was confused with other documentation like the INRIA person model :\

Comment: @RafaelRuiz it's not going to be a walk in the park... but take a look at the faster-rcnn paper - I believe it focuses mainly on improving the training of the system.